# Using blocks in C

Tags: c, block

I have this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int a = 5;
{
    int b = 6;
}
printf("%d %d", a, b);
return 0;
}
```

I am attempting to see how using a block would effect this but the program doesn't work. Says b is undeclared, this is the example I was given. Anyone know what is wrong? Or is it possible that this is suppose to throw me and error BECAUSE the int b is declared and initialized within the block when the printf isn't in there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `b` *is* undeclared where you try to print it. Its scope extends from its creation to the end of its block, which is the closing brace *before* the `printf`.

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 42;  // <<-- Look here! Yes, you! Right here! :-)
    {
        int b = 6;
        printf ("In block: %d %d\n", a, b);
    }
    printf ("Ex block: %d %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

This has a `b` in scope at the point where you try to print it outside the block. It's not the `b` *within* the block but you'll find that out when the results are printed:

```
In block: 5 6
Ex block: 5 42
```